# Multiselect and mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, database, multi-select

I'm working in a searcher. I have a form with a multiselect which contains languages and in MySQL database I have one table called USERS with all the users registered in the web site and one table called USERS_LANGUAGES with the languages that the users have selected in their profile.

So, I need the query to get the users that speak all the languages selected in the multiselect.

My first option was:

```
SELECT u.id FROM users u INNER JOIN users_languages ul ON u.id=ul.id_user AND ul.id_language IN ($multiselect options separated by comma)
```

But this query shows the users who know SOME of that languages, not ALL OF THEM.

My second option is to do a loop and add a INNER JOIN for each language, like this:

```
SELECT id FROM users u INNER JOIN users_languages ul_1 ON u.id=ul_1.id_user AND ul_1.id_language = 1 INNER JOIN user_languages ul_2 ON u.id=ul_2.id_user AND ul_2.id_language = 2 ...
```

this query works, but I'm wondering if there is a simpler query to do this.

Comment: Modify your first statement to GROUP by user id, and add a HAVING clause that demands the COUNT of those records to be equal to the number of languages you are searching for (determine that number previously).

Comment: But if I select in the multiselect, p.e: English, Spanish, French and German ant the user speaks English, Spanish, Chinese and Arabic, the COUNT will be the same, and the user only speaks two of the four languages selected, won't be?

Comment: No, because the records for `Chinese` and `Arabic` are already excluded from what gets COUNTed because of the WHERE IN condition.

Answer (score 0):

So to build on @CBroes comment:
(I have used an IN clause as an example)

```
SELECT u.id 
FROM users u 
INNER JOIN users_languages ul 
ON u.id=ul.id_user 
AND ul.id_language 
IN ("English", "Spanish", "French", "German")
HAVING COUNT(distinct ul.id_language) = 4
```

So, like you said, if you matched:

```
("English", "Spanish", "French", "Arabic")
```

Ie Arabic instead of german, the distinct count would be 3, and not 4, therefore, it wouldn't end up in your resultset.
So you have to send the number in the count clause each time.